# Can't parse webgl object to my object

Tags: javascript, oop, webgl

I'm trying to make an object in javascript to contain a 3dObject and everyting related to it:vertex positions, normals, texture coordonates etc + the methods needed to handle it: loading the object, drawing etc.

The problem is that when I try to parse the WebGL context object, in my case gl, wich is declared global, in order to use specific methods like createBuffer(), bindBuffer(), javascript give's me the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createBuffer' of undefined"

This is the object code:

```
function object3D(gl){

this.vertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

this.textureCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

this.normalDirectionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
this.indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();

this.loadVertices = function (vertices, itemSize, numItems){
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    this.vertexPositionBuffer.numItems = numItems;
    this.vertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = itemSize;
}

this.loadNormals = function (normals, itemSize, numItems){
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalDirectionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(normals), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    this.normalDirectionBuffer.numItems = numItems;
    this.normalDirectionBuffer.itemSize = itemSize;
}

this.loadIndex = function (indexArray, itemSize, numItems){
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    this.indexBuffer.numItems = numItems;
    this.indexBuffer.itemSize = itemSize;
}

this.loadTexture = function (textureCoord, itemSize, numItems){
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.textureCoordBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(textureCoord),    gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    this.textureCoordBuffer.numItems = numItems;
    this.textureCoordBuffer.itemSize = itemSize;
}
```

}

This is how I try to create an instance of this object:

```
var cube1 = new object3D(gl);
```

WebGL context assign:

```
var gl;
function initGL(canvas){
try{
    gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
    gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
    gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
}catch(e){
}
if(!gl){
    alert("Could not initialise WebGL");
}
}
```

Outside any function and inside my object definition console.log(gl) says is undefined, but in other places it works just fine, altough it is declared global.

I have to mention that i have a solid background in c++ but i'm pretty new to javascript and handling objects in it.

Comment: Can you show us what `console.log( gl );` shows, as a first statement inside `object3D`. Also, can you show us the statement where you assign `gl` to become the WebGL webcontext object. Also, checkout three.js, it might save you a lot of time.

Comment: "Outside any function and inside my object definition console.log(gl) says is undefined, but in other places it works just fine, altough it is declared global." That tells me that `gl` is *not* a global. Where is your `var gl;` statement located? Is it truly in the global scope or is it inside a function?

Comment: My gl declaration it's just after the <script> tag outside any function.

Comment: Can you please past your whole code here ? It seems like you do things in the wrong order, but can't determine if it's true without the code :)

Comment: @SariMihai I'm working on a very similar program and have the same issue, did you resolve your problem Sari ?   also can anyone show me an example of an object oriented webgl program ? any help would be greatly appreciated,